# how to remove dbo role requirement for .net membership in SQL database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, scripting, membership

I am transitioning an application from Dev to QA. I have created an sql file to populate the database in the QA environment. In the QA environment I am using windows authentication on the db. My user has minimal permissions. I am comin up with the error

```
EXECUTE permission denied on object 'aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion', database 'QADB', schema 'dbo'.
```

when I try an log in. I noticed my db creation script has:

```
"CREATE ROLE [aspnet_Membership_BasicAccess] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]"
```

When I change the permissions of my user to dbo, the problem goes away.

I do not wish for my user to be dbo. Does anybody know what I can do to remedy this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grant the user the execute permission on the stored procedure, or better still, make sure the user is a member of the role and grant execute permissions to the role.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON aspnet_checkscemaversion TO aspnet_membership_basicaccess
```

Comment: Thanks, I had some trouble adding the user role but the Grant worked a treat.